# Apache + MySQL + PHP 5.4 Operator -> not interpreted

Tags: php, apache, xampp

Context:
Installed XAMPP (Apache, MySQL + PHP 5.4)

PHP run fine, for example:

```
<?php 
   echo "PHP has been installed successfully!";
?>
```

print PHP has been installed successfully!

but when I use the **T_OBJECT_OPERATOR**, PHP can't reconize it, for example:

```
<?
include_once('inc.start.php');
include_once('inc.login.php');

if ($logeado) {
  $seccion = 'index';
  include_once('cms/lib/class.control.actividades.php');
  $control = new ControlActividades($web, $db, $sesion);
  $accion = $web->getParam('accion', 'listar');
    include_once('inc.finish.php');

?>
```

the server prints

```
getParam('accion', 'listar');
include_once('inc.finish.php');?>
```

EDIT:
I discover that the file doesn't start with `<?php`

The project is not mine, someone else has done, how do he has gotten it to work?

Comment: What is the object `$web` ?

Comment: It dosent matter, any other file or line with the sintax '->' fail. I prove to put <?php and the file run well, so, how I can configure Apache to run .php without head <?php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP Short tags is the answer. It needs to be enabled in your PHP ini file `short_open_tag=On`

Comment: short_open_tag=On    Thanks a lot, I spent two hours :(